# CodeIgniter MY_Controller not working in web server

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I extended the CI_Controller and made my own controller to be extended.
Now everything works fine in localhost (xampp) but when I copied the files over to my web server, I get `500 internal server error` which is quite useless. Odd to me is the fact, that I get internal server error instead of codeigniter generated error.

Things I have tried so far:

1) tried libraries folder instead of core for MY_Controller

2) I have had problem with server only accepting lowercase file names so I tried my_controller and changing config file *prefix*, *main.php* extension and so on.
Both of these seems like useless tries anyways, cause I didn't get error saying it can't be found or something similar.

When I change my *main.php* controller to extend CI_Controller, everything works fine.

I know I haven't provided much information, but I have no idea what to provide. Again, it works in localhost.

Thanks for any input you might have.

Comment: Can you tell use more about the environment of your web server?

Comment: You use the url_rewriting ?

Comment: How are you updating the web server? Are you using git, or something like that, so you can do a `git status` to see what files had been changed? If just FTP/scp, make sure you've uploaded all the pertinent files. I'm thinking of the _config/config.php_ file especially, since it has the config line pertinent here: `$config['subclass_prefix']`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your config.php to.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and the .htacces of the site to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```